# Data::FormValidator prints hashref instead of string for invalid data

Tags: perl, hash, validation, cpan, catalyst

We develop a Catalyst app and my coworker started implementing form validation with `Catalyst::Plugin::FormValidator` which provides a shortcut to `Data::FormValidator`.

The validation seems to succeed and the display of missing entries works. But when displaying details for mismatched constraints the page contains a hashref like `HASH(0x784d80)`.

This is the hash we use to configure the validator (everything example code made up to test FormValidator first):

```
{
    required => [qw/email age sex/],
    optional => [qw/city name/],
    filters  => [qw/trim/],

    constraints => {
        name => sub { length $_[1] >= 2 },
        sex => sub  { $_[1] =~ /^(male)|(female)$/},
        age => sub { $_[1] =~ /^[0-9]{1,2}$/ },
        email => sub { Email::Valid->address(lc($_[1])) },
        city => sub { length $_[1] >= 5 },
    },

    msgs => {
        invalid => {
            field => {
                email => 'no valid e-mail address',
                age => 'no valid age between 01 and 99',
                },

                default => 'contains an invalid value',
            },

        missing => 'missing!',
    },

}
```

This is how we read the values:

```
    <tr>
        <td>E-mail address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="[% email %]" />* [% c.form.msgs.email %]</td>
    </tr>
```

For missing fields everything works fine. For invalid fields the value given to `invalid =>` is just printed out. If set to `invalid => "THIS IS INVALID!"` the string is printed and if set to `invalid => {}` the hashref is printed as e.g. `HASH(0x784d80)` (even for empty hash).

Can somebody explain why this is? We use the current version 4.66 of `Data::FormValidator` from CPAN.

**Update:** By dumping `[% c.forms %]` my coworker could verify that the validity of the fields is determined correctly. Just the string is set wrong and we don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msgs->{invalid}` key for your form validator options is a hash. [It is meant to be a string](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/Data-FormValidator-4.81/lib/Data/FormValidator.pm#msgs):

> Here's a more complex example that shows how to provide your own default message strings, as well as providing custom messages per field, and handling multiple constraints:
>
> ```
> msgs => {
>     ...
>
>     # Default invalid message, default's to "Invalid"
>     invalid => 'Problematic!',
>
>     ...
> }
> ```

You should be able to use the `constraints` key in the `msgs` hash for per invalid field error messages:

```
constraints => {
    'date_and_time' => 'Not a valid time format',
    # ...
}
```

However, I am also currently trying to use the `constraints` and it is not having any effect, so the feature of field dependent error messages may not actually exist.

Comment: I added a quote to your answer. I am not working at the employer I was working for back then. You're probably right that only scalar strings work as message for invalid values. In contrast to the time of writing the question I do now understand what actually happened: Our hash was printed and stringified. Its structure never made a difference for `Data::FormValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo in your html:

```
[% c.form.msgs.email %]
```

should read

```
[% c.form.msgs.invalid.field.email %]
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. I think it's just another method to access the strings when iterating over the invalid fields. The result was the same.